# SmartBook Surfer - Bootmanager broken after ROM-flash

Tags: custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery, boot-loop

I recently installed the VegaComb ROM to my Smartbook Surfer MN10U.
Obviously I got the wrong ROM, which causes a boot loop.

The worse problem is, that I'm now unable to access the Clockwork Bootmanager. Since the Smartbook seems to have no connection options to a PC (as far as I researched, there is no cable to plug it to USB).

So what I'm basically asking is:

- Is there a possibillity to connect the Smartbook to a PC?
- Is it possible to make the Bootmanager accessible, without such a connection?
- Is it possible to install a new ROM without said connection, and without the Bootmanager?

Comment: Does it have a microUSB port? What ports does it have?

Comment: none. That's the problem. no microUSB and no other obvious ports.

Comment: The only port that might help is the port that's used to connect with the dock. But the dock has also just the usual usb ports and a hdmi port. Might there be a chance that USB Crossover might be possible?